# struct: Storage size unknown, or variable undeclared

Tags: c

I want to call a function `low_level_init` which has signature

```
void low_level_init(struct netif *netif)
```

I have tried

```
struct netif dummy;
low_level_init(&dummy);
```

but I get the error

> storage size of 'dummy' isn't known

I have also tried (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772897/storage-size-of-struct-isnt-known-c))

```
extern struct netif dummy;
low_level_init(&dummy);
```

but then I get the error

> error: 'dummy' undeclared (first use in this function)

How can I call `low_level_init`?

Comment: You need to give a definition for struct netif, perhaps it's in a header you forgot to include?

Comment: Add `#include <net/if.h>` to the end of the "include" section at the top of your file. It should come after all other headers; the problem should go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the header file where that structure is defined.
Otherwise the compiler cannot know how much space to reserve.

Comment: And what happens when it's not declared in a header?

Comment: You CAN declare a pointer to an undefined struct (as sizes of pointers are always the same), but you cannot declare a variable of an undefined type. It just can't work.

Comment: My point was that this is something you should add to your answer. I don't think there's a guarantee in the standard that all pointer sizes are always the same, is there?

Comment: Yes, all pointer sizes are always of the same size by definition.

Comment: In practice, this is often true and I've never encountered anything different, but that does not mean that there's a guarantee. Please quote an authoritative source. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399003/is-the-sizeofsome-pointer-always-equal-to-four

Comment: Of course there can be differences between pointer sizes on different systems, but on the SAME system, pointers have the same size. Just check K&R if you want...

Comment: K&R is not the standard. But beyond that, you're missing the point of the accepted answer on that other question. There are some people commenting on that answer that I would regard as C and C++ experts who did not correct it. Read the first line. One of the two of your is wrong. I'm asking for you to quote an authoritative source. If you don't want to, that's cool. Just don't act like you are discussing facts when you're discussing your working experience.